# Error sincronización de hilos con la clase Lock en Java

Tags: java

este es mi primer post, antes que nada si te sobra el tiempo, ganas de ayudar adelante =).

Tengo un problema en la sincronización de hilos, el programa que estoy haciendo simula una carrera, al principio tiene que decir a todos los corredores menos al primero, después de eso, dice tres fases que son: cogiendo el relevo; corriendo; y dándolo.

Entonces tendría que quedar algo así la salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y mi resultado es asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me he visto una serie de video, y se puede hacer con join(), pero lo he intentado y tampoco, tengo el uso de block para que no entre ningún hilo mas, pero entran en desorden

`import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

/**
 *
 * @author BryanGonzalez
 */
public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            Corredor r = new Corredor(i);
            Thread t = new Thread(r);
            t.start();
        }
    }

}

class Corredor implements Runnable {
    //Variables.
    private final int nCorredor;
    private Lock bloqueo = new ReentrantLock();

    //Constructor
    public Corredor(int num) {
        nCorredor = num;
    }

    //Metodos.
    public void carrera() {
        if (nCorredor == 0) {
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Corredor " + nCorredor + " esperando en la salida.");
    }
    public void empieza() {
        bloqueo.lock();
        try {
            System.out.println("Corredor " + nCorredor + " coge el relevo.");
            System.out.println("Corredor " + nCorredor + " corriendo.");
            System.out.println("Termino el corredor " + nCorredor + " pasa el testigo al siguiente.");
        } finally {
            bloqueo.unlock();
        }
    }

    //Metodo Run.
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int c = 0;
        try {
            carrera();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            empieza();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("Hilo interrumpido.");
        }
    }
}`

Comment: podrias mirar el [tour] solo para saber como funciona la plataforma.. muy buena primera pregunta.. muy bien formulada...

Comment: esta pregunta me saco una sonrisa XD, bienvenido y muy buena primera pregunta.

Comment: Hola. Acabo de probar tu código tal cual lo presentas y tras 10 o 12 ejecuciones obtengo siempre el mismo resultado. Similar al que presentas como bueno, solo que termina con el corredor tres. Puede ser que tu problema se deba a algo externo al código? alguna configuración o algo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

al final lo solucione de la siguiente manera, por si alguien le interesa:

Asi quedo la clase principal, como veis, lo que hice fue llamar a la fase "espera", desde un for-each antes de iniciar los hilos.

```
<code>
    
public class Principal {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            
            ArrayList<Corredor> corredores = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                corredores.add(new Corredor(i));
                corredores.get(i).espera();
            }

            for (Corredor corredore : corredores) {
                Thread t = new Thread(corredore);
                t.start();
                try {
                    t.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
            }

            System.out.println("FIN!");
            System.out.println("Todos los hilos han terminado la carrera de revelos.");
        }

    }
</code>
```

Y la clase Corredor, cambie algunas partes.

```
class Corredor implements Runnable {
    //Variables.

    private final int nCorredor;
    private Lock bloqueo = new ReentrantLock();

    //Constructor
    public Corredor(int num) {
        nCorredor = num;
    }

    //Metodos.
    public void espera() {
        bloqueo.lock();
        try {
            if (nCorredor != 0) {
                System.out.println("Corredor " + nCorredor + " esperando en la salida.");
            }

        } finally {
            bloqueo.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void empieza() {
        bloqueo.lock();
        try {
            System.out.println("Corredor " + nCorredor + " coge el relevo.");
            System.out.println("Corredor " + nCorredor + " corriendo.");
            System.out.println("Termino el corredor " + nCorredor + " pasa el testigo al siguiente.");
        } finally {
            bloqueo.unlock();
        }
    }

    //Metodo Run.
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int c = 0;
        try {
            empieza();
            long tardo=  (long)(Math.random() * 2000);
            sleep(tardo);
            //System.out.println("\tCorredor " + nCorredor + " tardo: " +  ((float)tardo/1000) + " segundos.");
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("Hilo interrumpido.");
        }
    }
}
```